# Ajax.BeginForm duplicate elements in _layout after insert

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I insert data to database using Ajax.BeginForm, but there's a problem!
when I click insert button after inserting data, some element in layout.cshtml duplicate, please see image below to understand it better
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lnVo.jpg)

this is model

```
public class student
{
    [Key]
    public int studentID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string studentName { get; set; }
}
```

this is create action of studentsController

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "studentID,studentName")] student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(student);
    }
```

this is view

```
@model ajaxbegin.Models.student

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<div id="ajaxBeginDiv">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "students", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod =          "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ajaxBeginDiv" }))
{ @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>student</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.studentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.studentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.studentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and this is layout page (default asp.net mvc _layout.cshtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-    toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area     = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I provided a sample you can download from here [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=60762732248017858668), for test purpose.